# how I can cut the label "img" using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri

how I can cut the label "img" using Nokogiri?

The label **img** it's inside on the tag description

The xml:

```
<item>
  <title>
    Title
  </title>
  <link>
    www.example.com
  </link>
  <description>
    <A HREF="example.com" /></A> <IMG border="1" src="http://www.example.com/1.jpg" /> </A>     <BR/> Length: 22:01 <BR/> Keywords: example
</description>
</item>
```

I would like to get "http://www.example.com/1.jpg"

thank you very much! Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `at_css` method to locate the node and then extract the value of the `src` attribute.  For example:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML('YOUR_XML_HERE')
doc.at_css('IMG')['src'] # http://www.example.com/1.jpg
```

I'd recommend checking out the [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials) documentation and/or the [cheat sheet](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/Cheat-sheet).  There's plenty of good resources out there to point you in the right direction.